# Bootstrap Table remove row if column have no data

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, wcf, bootstrap-table

Hi have this WCF Service and consuming that is working. My problem is column 7 may be empty, so in the client side i want to remove all rows that have column 7 empty. Any help will be welcome.

```
function GetPedidosAll(muser) {
jQuery.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: "/_vti_bin/XP/Requests.svc/GetPedidosListAll/" + muser +
         "/" + $("#sel_state").val() + "/" + $("#sel_project").val(),

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#lista_pedidos").bootstrapTable({
            data: data
        });
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, status) {
        $("#img_Progress").hide();
        MessPopups("e", status.message);
    }
});}
```

Thank You, 
JL

Comment: why not filter the "data" either in your success or the service before creating the table, rather than removing rows afterwards

Comment: You can filter your data onsuccess rather than calling an additional jquery functionality for removing row.

Comment: Thanks for point me to the good way, lot's of hours working in a row.

Answer (score 0):

```
  success: function (data) {
        data = jQuery.grep(data, function (a) {
            return a.Permissao !== "";
        });

        $("#lista_pedidos").bootstrapTable({
            data: data
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation with your solution.

Comment: I'm filtering my Service Property passing to an Array with JavaScript  using "jQuery.grep" http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/ in order to not return "a.Permissao" that contain empty values overriding the "data". In this case the "data" is filtered without all empty rows for the criteria